# Transmission lines in paralell for RS485

Tags: transmission-line, rs485, characteristic-impedance

I have a system with two RS485 transceivers connected by a 300 meters long cable, with 6 wires inside it. In this case, 3 paralell wires of this cable are being used for the "A" signal and the other 3 paralell wires for the "B" signal, resulting in 3 identical transmission lines in paralell, and it's known that the characteristic impedance of this arrangement is 100 ohm, which is good for RS485.
The characteristic impedance for RS485 systems is between 100 ohm and 150 ohm, nominal is 120 ohm.

I want to use only one of this wires for signal "A" and other for signal "B", and I need the impedance of this new arrangement. How can I calculate this?

Old arrangement:

[image: Old arrangement]Z_0=100 ohm

New arrangement:

[image: New arrangement]Z_0=?

Complete system:

[image: Complete]

Edit:
All internal wires are 26 AWG and 300 meters long. They are all paralell to each other, not twisted pair. Also, the whole cable is shielded, just like it was in the old arrangement.
About the remaining wires, two will be used for a DC signal, one for RS485 signal ground, and the last one is not connected to anything. The updated image with the new arrangement is the following:
[image: Update]

Signal ground is connected to both ends grounds, with a 100 ohm resistor between the cable and grounds. Shielding is grounded at only one end without any resistor, like it was in the old arrangement.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It can only be guessed because no dimensions are known. All wires interact strongly with each other if they are parallel. If you happen to plan to use the released wires for other signals prepare to high crosstalk except if the signals are DC or have very low frequency. Maybe you should tell how the 6 wires are placed in the cable. Someone could know the result due his experience. Measuring the transmission characteristics in the new configuration would tell the asked thing without calculations but the other wires should be connected as you are going to connect them when they are free.

Comment: This question is a confusing because the characteristic impedance is related to the dimensions of the cable. Usually cables use a twisted pair to reduce noise and provide the characteristic impedance. Provide a datasheet or dimensions of the geometry

Comment: It'll be a little bit more. Inductance will slightly increase and capacitance will slightly decrease.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: If 3 cables makes 100 ohms, one cable will make 300 ohms. Seems very easy to calculate to me.

Comment: One more comment: If Signal GND and DC negative are the same, you connect them al together with the unconnected wire. Use all the remaining wires for common ground. What's the difference between Signal GND and DC negative ?